# Where can I find a PDF of the Commission on Industrial Relations?

Tags: human-rights, labour-history

Where can I find good primary source website?

I need to find a PDF of the [Commission on Industrial Relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_on_Industrial_Relations).

But, the only place that I can find it is within the University of Miami website, which requires a password. If someone could direct me to a primary source website, or better yet, the PDF of the Commission on Industrial Relations, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full text of the Walsh Commission in html:  http://www.archive.org/stream/industrialrelati01unitrich/industrialrelati01unitrich_djvu.txt

here is the text on Google Books:  http://books.google.com/books?id=CtgJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

here is a pdf of the text from Cornell Library:  http://ia600504.us.archive.org/20/items/cu31924002663197/cu31924002663197.pdf

here are multiple links to the text via the Internet Archive:  http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22United+States.+Commission+on+Industrial+Relations%22